# ORDER BY FIELD Not Ordering by id number specified

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have run a query which picks the rows by id specified by another database call which belongs to a drag and drop menu layout builder.

I cant get the order by field to work correctly.

Either I am doing it incorrectly or I have just miis-understood the ORDER BY FIELD() sql query.

Here is the query:

```
$databasemenustring = '2,3,1,4';
$datamenu = $pdo->query("SELECT id, name, title, slug FROM pages WHERE id IN({$databasemenustring2}) AND islive=1 ORDER BY FIELD('id', {$databasemenustring})");
```

At present it just ordering by id desc.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you provide the table definition (create table ...) and some sample data as insert statements that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Lennart thank you for commenting, the create table is standard, the id is an int and set as primary and  to auto increment and the rest is standard with a varch, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Change ORDER BY FIELD('id',
```

to

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id,
```

Here is an example, while passing the fieldname as string literal it does not preserve the order as specified

```
mysql> select idfields from fields where idfields in (132,124,130,125) order by field('idfields',132,124,130,125);
+----------+
| idfields |
+----------+
|      124 |
|      125 |
|      130 |
|      132 |
+----------+
```

And

```
mysql> select idfields from fields where idfields in (132,124,130,125) order by field(idfields,132,124,130,125);
+----------+
| idfields |
+----------+
|      132 |
|      124 |
|      130 |
|      125 |
+----------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, cant believe I missed that... 7 hours of working without a break is obviously causing issues.

Comment: Now get some break :)